# How to convert from varchar/numeric to Time in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with time field as  datatype *Numeric(6,0)* and it is showing 24 hour format something like this 100,150300,21000 etc.

here 100->00:01:00 (12:01AM)
I wrote something like this to store as varchar to get missing 0's before:

```
select
Right('000000'+ cast(FM_TIME as varchar(6)),6) FT_Time
from table;
```

Now how to convert this field to time to show in 12 hour format with AM or PM.

Can we convert directly from Numeric to time by adding leading 0's?

Comment: Ugh. Why are you storing time values as numbers? This is what the time datatype is for.

Comment: the data itself is in numeric format.. I don't know who created that table :(
I wanted to create a report on that table so I don't have any other option..
need to convert it to Time format so that it will be user friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible you should update that column to be a time datatype instead of numeric(6,0).

This works with the sample data you provided. Be careful though, you may have some values in your table that are invalid.

```
create table #Something
(
    FM_TIME numeric(6,0)
)

insert #Something
select 100 union all
select 150300 union all
select 21000 

select convert(varchar(15), convert(time, STUFF(STUFF(right(REPLICATE('0', 6) + CONVERT(varchar(6), FM_TIME), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')), 100)
from #Something

drop table #Something
```

Comment: Thanks Lange for the answer but unfortunately client is not interested to change the data-type on Table so I just want to change in select query alone. Is there a way to create a temp DB inside select itself

Comment: Did you see the query I posted? It converts those numbers to a date. In your system all you would need is the select statement. The rest of everything is the setup so you can see it actually working.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert this data to the SQL Server `time` data type, you can display it however you want (in your client).

(Formatting of data types should be pushed to the client whenever possible:  clients tend to be much better at it!)

Here's an expression that can convert a 6 digit number to a `time` value:

```
declare @timeNumber int = 235945
select   convert(time, 
            convert(varchar(2), @timeNumber / 10000) + 
            ':' +
            convert(varchar(2), (@timeNumber % 10000) / 100) + 
            ':' +
            convert(varchar(2), @timeNumber % 100)          
        )
```

This will return the following:

```
 23:59:45.0000000
```

You can then format this however you want.

Edited to add:  by request, the above expression as a query from a table:

Assuming the field name `FM_TIME` and the table name `MyTable` (because you didn't provide the table name in your example) and that you want the column you return to have the name `FT_TIME`:

```
select   FT_TIME = convert(time, 
            convert(varchar(2), T1.FM_TIME / 10000) + 
            ':' +
                    convert(varchar(2), (T1.FM_TIME % 10000) / 100) + 
            ':' +
            convert(varchar(2), T1.FM_TIME % 100)           
        )  
from     MyTable T1
```

Comment: Thanks Ann L. can you please provide a query which takes values from column in a table because i can use declare in sql server but when I create a report it won't allow that sort of syntax

Comment: @NaveenBodapati  I have added the query.

Comment: thanks, This is working fine for the values which has 6 digits but some values doesn't have 6 digits for them I have added replicate as mentioned by Sean Lange :)